# Update MySQL without specifying column names

Tags: mysql

I want to update a mysql row, but I do not want to specify all the column names.
The table has 9 rows and I always want to update the last 7 rows in the right order.
These are the Fields

```
id
projectid
fangate
home
thanks
overview
winner
modules.wallPost
modules.overviewParticipant
```

Is there any way I can update the last few records without specifying their names?
With an INSERT statement this can be done pretty easily by doing this:

```
INSERT INTO `settings`
VALUES (NULL, ...field values...)
```

So I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
UPDATE `settings`
VALUES (NULL, ...field values...)
WHERE ...statement...
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You always have to specify the column names, because UPDATE doesn't edit a whole row, it edits **specified** columns.
Here's a link with the UPDATE syntax:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 5):

If the two first columns make up the primary key (or a unique index) you could use [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)

So basically instead of writing

```
UPDATE settings
   SET fangate = $fangate,
       home = $home,
       thanks = $thanks
       overview = $overview,
       winner = $winner,
       modules.wallPost = $modules.wallPost,
       modules.overviewParticipant = $modules.overviewParticipant
WHERE id = $id AND procjectId = $projectId
```

You will write

```
REPLACE INTO settings
 VALUES ($id, 
         $projectId,
         $fangate,
         $home,
         $thanks
         $overview,
         $winner,
         $modules.wallPost,
         $modules.overviewParticipant)
```

Of course this only works if the row already exist, otherwise it will be created. Also, it will cause a DELETE and an INSERT behind the scene, if that matters.

Comment: +1 Provided that the `WHERE` clause for the update would otherwise filter solely on a match against a `UNIQUE` key.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it works on the `INSERT` because even if you didn't specify the column name but you have supplied all values in the `VALUE` clause. Now, in `UPDATE`, you need to specify which column name will the value be associated.

`UPDATE` syntax requires the column names that will be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Are you always updating the same table and columns?

In that case one way would be to define a stored procedure in your schema.
That way you could just do:

```
CALL update_settings(id, projectid, values_of_last_7 ..);
```

Although you would have to create the procedure, check the Mysql web pages for how to do this, eg:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't afford not specifying the column names.

You can refer to the [update documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).